# if selected field is of type picklist then display Picklist values for that field as input type selectoption next to it on visualforce

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dynamic, schema

I am trying to create visualforce page similar to workflow page(See attached image).
I have 3 columns 
1st is Field Name
2nd operator
3rd Value

I want value field as input type picklist if 1st column i.e Field name is of type picklist.

i.e if I am selecting field status Value should show picklists available in status field as picklist

Visualforce :

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Rule Criteria">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper" id="wtable">
        <apex:column headerValue="Ident">
            <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.ident}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Field">
            <apex:selectList value="{!wrapper.acc.WFCField__c}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!FieldSeletOptions}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Operator">
            <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.WFC_Operator__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Value">
            <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.acc.WFCField__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <!-- 
        <apex:column headerValue="Action">
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!delWrapper}" 
                rerender="wtable">
                <apex:param name="toDelIdent" value="{!wrapper.ident}" 
                    assignTo="{!toDelIdent}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:column>
        -->
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Code in controller get SelectOpions for field column:

```
public List<SelectOption> getFieldSeletOptions() {
    List<SelectOption> fieldOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    String type='Case';

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = 
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType caseSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = 
        caseSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    SelectOption optionNone = new SelectOption('', '--None--');
    fieldOptions.add(optionNone);

    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {

        System.debug('##Field API Name='+fieldName);// list of all field API name
        //It provides to get the object fields label.
        Schema.DisplayType fieldType = 
            fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
        if(fieldType != Schema.DisplayType.ID) {
            SelectOption option = new SelectOption(fieldName, 
                fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());
            fieldOptions.add(option);
        }
    }
    return fieldOptions;
}
```

Wrapper

```
public class WFCriteriaWrapper {
    public WFCriteria__c acc { get; private set; }
    public Integer ident { get; private set; }

    public WFCriteriaWrapper(Integer inIdent) {
        ident=inIdent;
        acc=new WFCriteria__c();
    }
}
```

[image]

Field column is nothing but fields on case. email Address is of type text so value should be of input type text. If I am selecting Status field which is Picklist on Case, then on Value column next to Status I want it as Picklist values of status.I should be able to select a picklist

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Here's a great [tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html).

Comment: Field column is nothing but fields on case. email Address is of type text so value should be of input type text. If I am selecting Status field which is Picklist on Case, then on Value column next to Status I want it as Picklist values of status.I should be able to select a picklist

Comment: Here's another similar [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18112/apex-form-load-select-list-based-on-selected-item-in-previous-select-list).